Log off (uitloggen) and log on
I'm making one reservation on this site https://bent.baanreserveren.nl/user/future after the first reservation has been made I have to log off an log on with a different name.
At this moment I use driver.close() after the first reservation and driver.get for starting the next reservation, this takes +/- 5 seconds. I think it would be faster to not use driver.close() but log off and log on. This is the element: <li class=""><a href="/auth/logout" class="">Uitloggen</a></li>
Unfortunately I didn't manage to log off (Uitloggen).

Can somebody help me?
This is the class which I have to use:

XPath
//*[@id="main-menu"]/li[7]
Selector:
#main-menu > li:nth-child(7)

XPath
//*[@id="main-menu"]/li[7]/a
Selector:
#main-menu > li:nth-child(7) > a
I'm using this within a python script and the url behind this uitloggen is: https://bent.baanreserveren.nl/auth/logout
I tried:
element = element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-menu"]/li[7]/a') element.click()
and
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-menu"]/li[7]/a') element.click()
Both of them are not directing to to log out url

Can you provide the code with which you use the selector and attempt to perform a click on that button?

Can you please edit your question and add this information? Also explain what went wrong, what you have done to debug that situation...

I did manage it with this code:
menu_item = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-menu"]/li[7]')
menu_item.click()

It is working.
